# Can't hide BackButton after performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: swift, layout, segue

In my application I have a login scene which embedded with `Navigation Bar`. after user logged in, I'm navigating to home scene which only embedded with `Tab Bar`. For navigating I'm using a Segue and this is my code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginSegue", sender: nil)
```

and in next scene `viewDidLoad` I'm trying to `hideBackButton` but it doesn't work

I tried all of this codes but BackButton still showing **so this is not duplicated question**:

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=true
    self.navigationController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=true
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this in your viewDidLoad method. It should work:

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Comment: im already doing that but not working

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now it should work!

Comment: thanks that worked but why `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true` doesn't work? or other ones?

Answer (score 2):

Put this line of code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
```

in your viewDidLoad method. Hope this will help you.

Comment: that doesn't worked